# Typo in Locked Question Detail

Tags: feature-request, locked-posts

On the locked detail for questions 
[image]

Please reword the description to fix the "[amount vs number](http://grammarist.com/usage/amount-number/)" grammar issue.  Either

- `...the high number of off-topic comments...`
- or something like `...the high amount of off-topic content...`

  I know it's a bit nitpicky, but I think it would make the message a bit more professional-looking.

Comment: I don't think the number is relevant. What's relevant is that there's a high volume of off-topic comments. And changing it to "content" is confusing.

Comment: I would settle for `high volume`.  I just think that the current wording sounds wrong.  Any fix works.

Comment: I guess you didn't read the second paragraph in the article you linked: "The distinction [between 'amount' and 'number'] tends to weaken, however, when we’re talking about great numbers. *The amount of people in the room* would sound wrong to many careful speakers of English, while *the amount of people in China* would not seem so glaringly wrong..." To be locked, a post needs to get an *astronomical* amount of off-topic comments ;)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot haha.  I'll grant that that number of comments would probably be rather large.  Keep in mind that "The distinct tends to weaken" still means that the use of "amount" is just closer to being preferred but not actually preferred.